# Can not start WLS as oracle user

Tags: weblogic12c

After configuring WLS I've got the following error. The problem is described here https://community.oracle.com/thread/1080487?tstart=0

```
<BEA-000362> <Server failed. Reason:

There are 1 nested errors:

java.lang.ClassCastException: com.octetstring.vde.backend.BackendRoot
        at weblogic.ldap.EmbeddedLDAP.start(EmbeddedLDAP.java:273)
        at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

Answer (score 1):

This response from Alfonso Vicente was very helpful. A similar response is at https://obieepedia.wordpress.com/2014/03/29/weblogic-startup-failure-backendroot-cannot-cast-to-backendstandard/

Yannick, I think someone started your WLS as root, so, there are many files with owner root, causing your error.

A way to fix the problem is to change the owner of that files back.

```
#(Solaris)
chown -R oracle:oragid /oracle/product/wls10320
#(Linux)
chown -R oracle.oragid /oracle/product/wls10320
```

(replace oragid for your oracle main group)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked with below.
Clean up the /cache and /tmp folders, DOMAIN_HOME/servers/AdminServer/tmp and and ../cache folder. Before that backup the YOUR_DOMAIN/servers/AdminServer/data/ldap folder.